# How to prevent jenkins from building a module while another one is building?

Tags: jenkins

I have the following build chain: A-->B
so when A is finished building the B building will start.

However, if the B build is in progress I don't want A to start a concurrent build until B is finished.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin

to prevent job A from starting while job B is currently in progress, it will still be triggered but will wait in the queue till it completes.

However that plugin only works for freestlye jobs.

If the A and B are pipeline jobs you might want to create a shared resource and then lock it during the building of B

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of executors on the 'master' to just 1. It is not advisable as it may slow down the process. You can set it in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > # of executors. It will make sure that no concurrent builds are executed. But beware, that it will apply to all the builds.